Error handling when executing multiple SQL statements with QSqlQuery
When I execute a QSqlQuery with multiple statements on a PostgreSQL database, it will not return an error if one of the statements failed. What can I get it to not return True (=success) if one of multiple statements failed?
For example if I have this table with two NOT NULL columns:
CREATE TABLE products (
  product_no integer NOT NULL,
  name text NOT NULL
);

and run INSERT INTO products (product_no) VALUES (2); on it, it should fail as null value in column "name" of relation "products" violates not-null constraint.
With a QSqlQuery only containing this specific statement, it does correctly return false (=error). But if I have more statements in the query, it will return true, making it impossible to know that something went wrong.
The docs say that SQLite does not support multiple statements and that the query will error, leading me to believe that PostgreSQL does support multiple statements.
Example Code
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery
from testcontainers.postgres import PostgresContainer


postgres = PostgresContainer("postgis/postgis:15-3.3", driver=None)
postgres.start()

db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QPSQL")
db.setHostName(postgres.get_container_host_ip())
db.setPort(int(postgres.get_exposed_port(postgres.port)))
db.setDatabaseName(postgres.dbname)
db.setUserName(postgres.username)
db.setPassword(postgres.password)
assert db.isValid()
assert db.open()

query = QSqlQuery()
if not query.exec("CREATE TABLE products (product_no integer NOT NULL, name text NOT NULL);"):
    print(f"a) Error: {query.lastError().text()} = BAD")
else:
    print("a) No error = GOOD")

print("-" * 23)
if not query.exec("INSERT INTO products (product_no) VALUES (1);"):  # violates NOT NULL
    print(f"b) Error: {query.lastError().text()} = GOOD")
else:
    print("b) No error = BAD")

print("-" * 23)
if not query.exec(
    """
    INSERT INTO products (product_no, name ) VALUES (2, 'inserted first');
    INSERT INTO products (product_no) VALUES (3);
    """
):  # second statement violates NOT NULL
    print(f"c) Error: {query.lastError().text()} = GOOD")
else:
    print("c) No error = BAD")

print("-" * 23)
if not query.exec(
    """
    INSERT INTO products (product_no) VALUES (4);
    INSERT INTO products (product_no, name ) VALUES (5, 'inserted second');
    """
):  # first statement violates NOT NULL
    print(f"d) Error: {query.lastError().text()} = GOOD")
else:
    print("d) No error = BAD")

print("-" * 23)
if not query.exec(
    """
    INSERT INTO products (product_no, name) VALUES (6, 'inserted with another a');
    INSERT INTO products (product_no, name ) VALUES (7, 'inserted with another b');
    """
):
    print(f"c) Error: {query.lastError().text()} = GOOD")
else:
    print("c) No error = BAD")

print("-" * 23)
query.exec("SELECT * FROM products;")
while query.next():
    print([query.record().value(i) for i in range(query.record().count())])

postgres.stop()


The output
a) No error = GOOD
-----------------------
b) Error: ERROR:  null value in column "name" of relation "products" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, null).
(23502) QPSQL: Unable to create query = GOOD
-----------------------
c) No error = BAD
-----------------------
d) Error: ERROR:  null value in column "name" of relation "products" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (4, null).
(23502) QPSQL: Unable to create query = GOOD
-----------------------
e) No error = GOOD
-----------------------
[6, 'inserted with another a']
[7, 'inserted with another b']

We see that INSERT INTO products (product_no, name ) VALUES (2, 'inserted first'); INSERT INTO products (product_no) VALUES (3); leads to no error according to QSqlQuery, which is wrong.
We also see that executing two statements with a single exec works.
The accompanying PostgreSQL logs
2024-10-11 07:39:51.587 UTC [83] ERROR:  null value in column "name" of relation "products" violates not-null constraint
2024-10-11 07:39:51.587 UTC [83] DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, null).
2024-10-11 07:39:51.587 UTC [83] STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO products (product_no) VALUES (1);
2024-10-11 07:39:51.587 UTC [83] ERROR:  null value in column "name" of relation "products" violates not-null constraint
2024-10-11 07:39:51.587 UTC [83] DETAIL:  Failing row contains (3, null).
2024-10-11 07:39:51.587 UTC [83] STATEMENT:  
            INSERT INTO products (product_no, name ) VALUES (2, 'inserted first');
            INSERT INTO products (product_no) VALUES (3);
            
2024-10-11 07:39:51.587 UTC [83] ERROR:  null value in column "name" of relation "products" violates not-null constraint
2024-10-11 07:39:51.587 UTC [83] DETAIL:  Failing row contains (4, null).
2024-10-11 07:39:51.587 UTC [83] STATEMENT:  
            INSERT INTO products (product_no) VALUES (4);
            INSERT INTO products (product_no, name ) VALUES (5, 'inserted second');

Here we see that SELECT true; INSERT INTO products (product_no) VALUES (2); did error. But QSqlQuery did not return false.
db.lastError() is also not set to an error.

How can I get the QSqlQuery to return false if any of its statement led to an error?

You can not add more than one query to a exec() - statement. This is not supported (yet).

Are you 100% sure? Is that documented somewhere? I am certain that it works when you have multiple non-erroring statements.

PostgreSQL does support multiple statements That's true for PostgreSQL. All errors you see are about the NOT NULL violation.

Yes, but for case c, QSqlQuery erroneously does not consider the exec to have failed.
